# Create new column based on how many rows, with condition based on another column, are within X days of current row date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My DF currently has just the first two columns DATE and RESULT and I want to create the third column N_RESULTS_EQUAL_1_PAST_60_DAYS:

```
DATE                        RESULT   N_RESULTS_EQUAL_1_PREVIOUS_60_DAYS
2018-12-26 23:13:43+00:00   1        0
2019-02-18 23:27:58+00:00   0        1
2019-02-28 15:02:33+00:00   0        0
2019-03-05 18:30:26+00:00   1        0
2019-05-21 14:54:52+00:00   1        0
2019-08-26 14:30:38+00:00   1        0
2019-09-19 15:51:01+00:00   1        1
2019-12-16 17:58:24+00:00   0        0
2021-02-23 03:50:33+00:00   0        0
2021-08-08 22:26:01+00:00   1        0
2021-09-01 18:04:46+00:00   0        1
```

For each row I want to check all the previous rows that are within 60 days of the current row and sum up how many RESULT == 1 these previous rows have. I can only think in a double for loop to solve this problem, which is not efficient. If there a more efficient way to solve this problem?

Edit 1: I made a mistake when first creating the N_RESULTS_EQUAL_1_PREVIOUS_60_DAYS column, I was not considering the RESULT == 1, I'm now fixing it.

Edit 2: I thought that having this simple example would be enough to solve the problem. However as it turns out, the best answer so far requires that the date is sorted, and I actually can't sort the date, here is why:

My actual problem have some IDs in it, and I must solve this problem to each individual ID. My DF is actually more like this:

```
DATE                        ID   RESULT   N_RESULTS_EQUAL_1_PREVIOUS_60_DAYS
2018-01-24 22:02:36+00:00   104  1        0
2018-05-15 18:27:17+00:00   104  0        0
2019-05-15 22:58:06+00:00   104  1        0
2019-07-22 15:17:55+00:00   104  1        0
2020-01-03 20:27:52+00:00   104  1        0
2018-12-26 23:13:43+00:00   105  1        0
2019-02-18 23:27:58+00:00   105  0        1
2019-02-28 15:02:33+00:00   105  0        0
2019-03-05 18:30:26+00:00   105  1        0
2019-05-21 14:54:52+00:00   105  1        0
2019-08-26 14:30:38+00:00   105  1        0
2019-09-19 15:51:01+00:00   105  1        1
2019-12-16 17:58:24+00:00   105  0        0
2021-02-23 03:50:33+00:00   105  0        0
2021-08-08 22:26:01+00:00   105  1        0
2021-09-01 18:04:46+00:00   105  0        1
2019-01-12 21:24:23+00:00   106  0        0
2019-05-28 08:03:55+00:00   106  1        0
2019-09-17 02:56:47+00:00   106  0        0
2020-05-06 17:20:55+00:00   106  0        0
2021-01-07 13:14:41+00:00   106  0        0
```

So, if I set my DATE column as index and then sort my index I end up messing my ID column.

Comment: Will you please add a sample dataframe containing your expected output?

Comment: maybe you should use `rolling()` to create `rolling window` which should give only last 60 days and then you could use `.sum()` or `.count()`, .`count_values()`, etc.

Comment: now you may need to add column with consecutive numbers - so you could use it to sort rows to original order after using `rolling()`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that 'DATE' is a DatetimeIndex, you can groupby the 'ID' and then use .rolling() which now works for ragged datetimes:

```
df['N_RESULTS_EQUAL_1_PREVIOUS_60_DAYS'] = df.groupby('ID').rolling('60D').sum().astype('int').droplevel(0)
```

I'm using the the original index to add the column here, which works, but I think a more robust solution would be to use 'ID'and 'DATE' to merge the original df with the df that contains the 60 day sums, so you can also try that. Also, I understand you don't want to include the 'RESULT' itself, only the sum from previous ones. In that case, just subtract it:

```
df['N_RESULTS_EQUAL_1_PREVIOUS_60_DAYS'] = df['N_RESULTS_EQUAL_1_PREVIOUS_60_DAYS'] - df['RESULT']
```

Output:

```
DATE                        ID  RESULT  N_RESULTS_EQUAL_1_PREVIOUS_60_DAYS
2018-01-24 22:02:36+00:00   104 1       0
2018-05-15 18:27:17+00:00   104 0       0
2019-05-15 22:58:06+00:00   104 1       0
2019-07-22 15:17:55+00:00   104 1       0
2020-01-03 20:27:52+00:00   104 1       0
2018-12-26 23:13:43+00:00   105 1       0
2019-02-18 23:27:58+00:00   105 0       1
2019-02-28 15:02:33+00:00   105 0       0
2019-03-05 18:30:26+00:00   105 1       0
2019-05-21 14:54:52+00:00   105 1       0
2019-08-26 14:30:38+00:00   105 1       0
2019-09-19 15:51:01+00:00   105 1       1
2019-12-16 17:58:24+00:00   105 0       0
2021-02-23 03:50:33+00:00   105 0       0
2021-08-08 22:26:01+00:00   105 1       0
2021-09-01 18:04:46+00:00   105 0       1
2019-01-12 21:24:23+00:00   106 0       0
2019-05-28 08:03:55+00:00   106 1       0
2019-09-17 02:56:47+00:00   106 0       0
2020-05-06 17:20:55+00:00   106 0       0
2021-01-07 13:14:41+00:00   106 0       0
```

Comment: Ok, so I guess 'DATE' isn't the index in your dataframe. I think .rolling() only works with datetimes, when it is an index, so use `df.index = df['DATE']` to set index to 'DATE' and then you can drop the 'DATE' column with `df.drop('DATE', axis=1, inplace=True)` or you can reset index after you've calculated the rolling windows with `df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)` if you would like to have dates as a column and not as an index. Hope this helps

Comment: It does help and work. But I unfortunately can't sort the date in this case. I'll explain it in my next edit.

Comment: @MatheusSchaly you may need to add column with consecutive numbers - so you could use it to sort rows to original order after using `rolling()`

Comment: But if I sort the dates the IDs sorting will be lost. Consequently, when I use `rolling()` I'll be getting the dates from different IDs, which is not what I want. For example, after sorting the dates, if I have the first row `date == 2018-11-10`, `result == 1`, `id == 100` and the second row `date == 2018-11-15`, `result == 0`, `id == 101`, then I'll have `N_RESULTS_EQUAL_1_PREVIOUS_60_DAYS == 1`, which could be wrong because I'm getting the date from a different ID. I need to do this task *to each individual ID*, I can't consider the date/result/whatever from `ID 100` in `ID 101`

Comment: Maybe I could break my dataframe into `df['ID'].nunique()` dfs, apply `rolling()`, and then concatenate it all back. I'm not sure if this would be better than a double foor loop though

Comment: This solved the problem:
`df.set_index('DATE').sort_index().groupby('ID')['RESULT'].rolling('60D').sum().astype(int).values - df['RESULT']`
Include it in your answer and I'll accept it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems @MethodGuy already described how to use `rolling()` when I was working on solution but I put my version because I have something else.

And I also get the same result as @MethodGuy which are different then `N_RESULTS_EQUAL_1_PREVIOUS_60_DAYS` so I checked how many days is between first and last date in `rolling window`.

I'm not sure but maybe it should be `61D` (minus last date in function) to get `past 60D`

---

If you would have `DATE` as `index` then you could use `rolling('60D')` to create `rolling window` and work with only last 60 days - and then you can use `.sum()`, `.count()`, etc. You can also use `.apply(func)` to run own function which can skip current date

```
def result(data):
    return data[:-1].sum()

df['result'] = df['RESULT'].rolling('60D').apply(result).astype(int)
```

---

Minimal working code which shows `.sum()`, `.count()`, `.apply()` to calculate sum without current day. I also use `.apply()` to calculate days bettween first and last date in `rolling window`

```
text = '''DATE                        RESULT   60_DAYS
2018-12-26 23:13:43+00:00   1        0
2019-02-18 23:27:58+00:00   0        1
2019-02-28 15:02:33+00:00   0        1
2019-03-05 18:30:26+00:00   1        2
2019-05-21 14:54:52+00:00   1        0
2019-08-26 14:30:38+00:00   1        0
2019-09-19 15:51:01+00:00   1        1
2019-12-16 17:58:24+00:00   0        0
2021-02-23 03:50:33+00:00   0        0
2021-08-08 22:26:01+00:00   1        0
2021-09-01 18:04:46+00:00   0        1'''

import pandas as pd

import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s{2,}')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
del df['DATE']

print(df)

def result1(data):
    data = data[:-1]
    return data.sum()

def result2(data):
    data = data[:-1]
    return len(data[ data == 1 ])

def days(data):
    return (data.index[-1] - data.index[0]).days

window = df['RESULT'].rolling('60D')

df['sum']     = window.sum().astype(int)
df['count']   = window.count().astype(int)
df['result1'] = window.apply(result1).astype(int)
df['result2'] = window.apply(result2).astype(int)
df['days']    = window.apply(days).astype(int)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
                           RESULT  60_DAYS  sum  count  result1  result2  days
DATE                                                                          
2018-12-26 23:13:43+00:00       1        0    1      1        0        0     0
2019-02-18 23:27:58+00:00       0        1    1      2        1        1    54
2019-02-28 15:02:33+00:00       0        1    0      2        0        0     9
2019-03-05 18:30:26+00:00       1        2    1      3        0        0    14
2019-05-21 14:54:52+00:00       1        0    1      1        0        0     0
2019-08-26 14:30:38+00:00       1        0    1      1        0        0     0
2019-09-19 15:51:01+00:00       1        1    2      2        1        1    24
2019-12-16 17:58:24+00:00       0        0    0      1        0        0     0
2021-02-23 03:50:33+00:00       0        0    0      1        0        0     0
2021-08-08 22:26:01+00:00       1        0    1      1        0        0     0
2021-09-01 18:04:46+00:00       0        1    1      2        1        1    23
```